# How to add new database in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, database

When I'm trying to add new database, I will always have a "create failed for database" error. Image is below.

[image: Add New Database Error(Create Failed For Database)]

And also, I've read online that you should change the user permissions in order for it to work. So I went to security -> login -> server roles and then I checked dbcreator. After I've hit OK, there's another error "Add member failed for server". Image is below.

[image: Change Login Properties]

By the way, I'm using GearHost for free database hosting.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a support question to them

Comment: Try running the Server Management Studio as admin.

Comment: From which user you have logged-in?? Does it has enough permission to create or alter database?? Check out this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186312.aspx#Restrictions)

Comment: The error message is pretty explanatory - you do not have permission on the user to do what you want to do.

Comment: @vivekkv - I'm already running it as admin. Still not working.

Comment: @Rohit Kumar - I logged in using the account that I have created in GearHost. It indicates there that my permission is "read and write" ?. Sorry I'm a total noob at this point.

Comment: @BrunoEarth try to login with "sa" account and then perform the desired work.

Comment: @Rohit Kumar - Okay but I don't know the password for the "sa" account. Cannot change it either.

Comment: @BrunoEarth - Then ask to them who knows it(DBA) or ask for providing dbcreator role to your user from DBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you can't create databases directly from Management Studio on shared hosting.

To create new database on GearHost hosting:

- Go to https://my.gearhost.com/databases
- Pick unique database name
- Select database type (MSSQL in your case) and plan (Free/Standard)
- Hit Create Empty (if you want new blank database) or Restore from backup (if you want use your existing one).

After that you will be able to connect to newly created database using username & password provided under the database details page.

Same applies to new database users - you should create them under the GearHost control panel (database details page) but not from Management Studio.